# Customize in kv py object

Tags: python, widget, kivy, kivy-language

What I need is to know how I do to customize an object already instantiated.

```
#Archivo py
class Principal(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Principal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._principal=Screen(name='Principal')
        self._layout=AnchorLayout()
        self._boton=Button(text='Hola')

        self._layout.add_widget(self._boton)
        self._principal.add_widget(self._layout)
        self.add_widget(self._principal)
```

```
#Archivo kv
#:kivy 1.11.1
<Principal>:
    root._boton.text:'hola2'    #This line throws me error. How do I change the text of the button?
```

Comment: Please ask questions on [so] in English.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that kivy is expecting an attribute of `Principal` in the `kv` rule. Since there is no such attribute it throws an error. You can avoid that error by creating an attribute that does what you want. If you change the `Principal` class to:

```
class Principal(ScreenManager):
    button_text = StringProperty('Hola') # new attribute

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Principal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._principal=Screen(name='Principal')
        self._layout=AnchorLayout()
        self._boton=Button(text=self.button_text)  # use of new attribute
        self._layout.add_widget(self._boton)
        self._principal.add_widget(self._layout)
        self.add_widget(self._principal)
```

This creates an attribute named `button_text` in the `Principal` class and sets the `text` of `_boton` to that attribute. Then in the `kv` file, reference that new attribute:

```
<Principal>:
    button_text:'hola2'    #This line no longer throws me error.
```